# Input type password mostrar senha

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Segui alguns tutoriais para conseguir por o visor no input
Como por exemplo este aqui :http://jsfiddle.net/cj3kmxL4/1/
Porém quando rodo no meu pc ele da o seguinte erro:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Procure sempre postar o codigo em forma de texto e não em forma de imagem. Desse modo fica mais fácil analisar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Era só por um onloadm pois o código tava tentando pegar o valor antes do carregamento do DOM

```
window.onload=function(){
 var input = document.querySelector('#input input');
                var img = document.querySelector('#input img');
                var visivel = false;
                img.addEventListener('mousedown', function () {
                visivel = true;
                input.type = 'text';
                });
                window.addEventListener('mouseup', function (e) {
                if (visivel) visivel = !visivel;
                input.type = 'password';
                });
            }
```

Comment: Antes do carregamento do DOM é este: `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){});`... o `onload` só é disparado após o carregamento total da página (imagens, scripts etc.)